# How to import the java code as a project to IDE?

Tags: java, ide

I download a API form USPS, and when I tried to import them to my IDE(netbeans), I got error message. So I tried Eclipse is also not work.

So, is there a way to import them to my IDE? :)

Comment: What is `"a API form USPS"`[sic]?

Comment: The United States Postal Service? Which IDE (netbeans or eclipse)? How does it "not work"? What is included in your API?

Comment: This post don't follow any of the SO guidelines :
- What API are you talking about ?
- Import what exactly ?
- What is the error message ?
- Which version of NetBeans / Eclipse are you using ?
- What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in netbeans IDE add them as library.
click on your project node you will see library node and then right click on library node you can add jar or library to your own project.